# Visual Studio NPM Task Runner fails, but running task outside of VS runs fine

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, babeljs

I'm working on bringing a ReactJS app over to a .NET setup. I'm trying to run an NPM script from the task runner (or anywhere within VS.) When I run my build command from the task runner, it fails due to an ES6 arrow function within one of my scripts. However, if I load up `cmd.exe` or powershell, navigate to the project and run it by hand, it runs perfectly.

Any idea why Visual Studio would be doing this?

The output looks something like this:

```
> cmd.exe /c npm run build --color=always
> ...cmd1
> ...cmd2
> mocha --reporter spec tools/testSetup.js "Scripts/app/**/*.test.js"
C:\Code\HAL\dev\Test\HALTest\HALReact\tools\testSetup.js:40
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at C:\Code\HAL\dev\Test\HALTest\HALReact\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:220:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Code\HAL\dev\Test\HALTest\HALReact\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:217:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Code\HAL\dev\Test\HALTest\HALReact\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:469:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\HAL\dev\Test\HALTest\HALReact\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:404:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

The file that it errors on basically just sets up JSDOM:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

// Register babel so that it will transpile ES6 to ES5
// before our tests run.
require('babel-register')();

// Disable webpack-specific features for tests since
// Mocha doesn't know what to do with them.
require.extensions['.css'] = function () {return null;};
require.extensions['.png'] = function () {return null;};
require.extensions['.jpg'] = function () {return null;};

// Configure JSDOM and set global variables
// to simulate a browser environment for tests.
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

documentRef = document;  //eslint-disable-line no-undef
```

Again, I can run this from the CLI directly, and it will work. It has babel-register invoked. I'm just not sure why it wants to error here. If I swap out the arrow function with a regular function, I get other errors in my tests, so it's like the task runner is not able to find babel, or is losing some environmental setting.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am facing the same issue and have to use gulp unnecessarily :(

Comment: I did not. I pretty much gave up on VS completely.

Comment: Oh...that is unfortunate. Thanks for the response though.